# The `initialStatus` argument for `Prerender` must be a natural number

Tags: next.js, deployment, vercel, next.js13, prerender

**The `initialStatus` argument for `Prerender` must be a natural number.**

I am trying to deploy my next.js 13 app on vercel then I'm getting this error. If someone knows anything about this issue then please share your answers below

***log while deploying on vercel :***
[Log screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/49iBF.png)

And my next.config.js file looks like this:

```js
/** @type {import('next').NextConfig} */
const nextConfig = {
  experimental: {
    appDir: true,
  },
  images: {
    domains: ["res.cloudinary.com"],
  },
};

module.exports = nextConfig;
```

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same problem; in my case, I removed a try/catch statement inside of Route Handler, and then my project was built on Vercel.